# RSpec doesn't compare objects properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Page do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    create(:page).should be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a title" do
    build(:page, title: nil).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "finds record" do
    page = create(:page, title: 'heyo')
    Page.unscoped.where(:title => 'heyo').should  == page
  end

  it "finds record with same attributes" do
    page = create(:page, title: 'heyo')
    Page.unscoped.where(:title => 'heyo').first.attributes.each do |name, val|
      expect(page[name]).to eq(val)
    end
  end
end
```

I have the following factory:

```
model_statuses = ['published', 'draft']
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :page do
    title         { Faker::Lorem.word + ' Page' }
    slug          { title ? title.parameterize : nil }
    intro         { Faker::Lorem.sentence 10 }
    content       { Faker::Lorem.sentences(5).join ' ' }
    status        { model_statuses.sample }
  end
end
```

Tests fail with:

```
Failures:

  1) Page finds record with same attributes
     Failure/Error: expect(page[name]).to eq(val)

       expected: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 23:33:47 MSK +04:00
            got: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 23:33:47 MSK +04:00

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
     # ./spec/models/page_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/page_spec.rb:19:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/page_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Page finds record
     Failure/Error: Page.unscoped.where(:title => 'heyo').should  == page
       expected: #<Page id: 1, slug: "heyo", title: "heyo", intro: "Sed sint et nesciunt earum libero eveniet est cupid...", content: "A sunt ab exercitationem quas ex incidunt numquam. ...", created_at: "2014-01-24 19:33:47", updated_at: "2014-01-24 19:33:47", status: "draft">
            got: [#<Page id: 1, slug: "heyo", title: "heyo", intro: "Sed sint et nesciunt earum libero eveniet est cupid...", content: "A sunt ab exercitationem quas ex incidunt numquam. ...", created_at: "2014-01-24 19:33:47", updated_at: "2014-01-24 19:33:47", status: "draft">] (using ==)
```

Why these objects and their attributes aren't the same and how do I properly check for object equality?

Answer (score 2):

I see the problems to be in comparison of different objects in your tests.

The following test:

```
  it "finds record" do
    page = create(:page, title: 'heyo')
    Page.unscoped.where(:title => 'heyo').should  == page
  end
```

When you get to this test you already have one `page` object from `"has a valid factory"` test.  So after this test executes you have two page objects, first with title `nil` and second with title `heyo`.  Now when you try to match with `should` in the next line your `Page.unscoped.where(:title => 'heyo')` does return expected result, i.e. an array of `Page` objects with title 'heyo'.  You're getting an array and you're comparing the array with an Object, so that's going to fail.

Then the reason your second test `"finds record with same attributes"` is failing is because you are expecting the first `Page` object to be equal to last `Page` object, so this is also going to fail.

So the fixes would be on the following two tests:

```
  it "finds record" do
    page = create(:page, title: 'heyo')
    Page.unscoped.where(:title => 'heyo').last.should  == page
  end

  it "finds record with same attributes" do
    page = create(:page, title: 'heyo')
    Page.unscoped.where(:title => 'heyo').last.attributes.each do |name, val|
      expect(page[name]).to eq(val)
    end
  end
```

Note the use of `last` in both tests.

The [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem is something that you might be interested in.  It allows you to clean the database before each tests.  Recommend looking at it.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about earlier saves. Adding `.last` made `"finds record"` pass. But `"finds record with same attributes"` fails and I inspected to see: `(byebug) page.updated_at.to_f 1390598731.7451882 (byebug) page_saved.updated_at.to_f 1390598731.745188` so there is a time difference. Now I'm confused. Why one test passes and other fails?

Answer (score 1):

The source of both errors is the same.

You are comparing one of the dates, created_at, updated_at, and they don't seem to have the same value.

Notice that the dates only go to the second when printed as strings - they might differ at a lower level than that.

Either exclude the dates from the comparison, or do a raise/inspect in the code at the site of the failure to see if the fractional seconds are differing between the two items.

Another trick you can use is to stub out Time.now/Time.new within the scope of your spec, so that you will always get a consistent result.

Normally you will stub out/abuse Time.now in a before :each block inside the context of your spec.  You want to make the scope as narrow as possible because overriding that method can have all sorts of weird side effects if you aren't careful where you do it.

Comment: Thanks. What's the best way to stub `Time.now`? How are objects normally compared in RSpec? What are best practices?

Comment: How would I raise/inspect in the code to see the actual values?

Comment: @leemour When I say raise/inspect, I literally mean inside your failing test to call `raise page.inspect`, for example in your "finds record" example.

Comment: That would give me just 1 value. How can I raise to see the difference between 2 objects?

Comment: I inspected and got results `(byebug) page.updated_at.to_f
1390598731.7451882
(byebug) page_saved.updated_at.to_f
1390598731.745188` so there is a time difference. But object equality in test `"finds record"` is successful after I added `.last` to `Page.unscoped.where(:title => 'heyo')`. Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

You must freeze the time in your case, use [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) for instance